# Custom UITableViewCell register class in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

In my application, I fill the table on the basis of the array. The table uses custom UITableViewCell. Everything works fine, table is filled. Then I add Search Display Controller to my UITableViewController, no write code to handle the search, simply add the controller. When you run the application, the table is still filled.But if I try to click on the search bar, I get the error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CitiesListCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

I try to add to my viewDidLoad function in UITableViewController line:

`self.tableView.registerClass(MyCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)`

Launch the application and immediately get the error:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

In line `cell.cellMyCity.text = cellText`

What am I doing wrong?

This is my Custom UITableViewCell class:

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var cellMyImage: UIImageView
@IBOutlet var cellMyCity: UILabel
@IBOutlet var cellMyCountry: UILabel
@IBOutlet var cellMyTemp: UILabel

init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}
}
```

This is code for cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell!

    if cell == nil {
        cell = MyCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
    }

    let cellText: String? = dataWeatherSelectedCity[indexPath.row].name as  String
    println("Строка: \(cellText)")
    cell.cellMyCity.text = cellText

    let cellSubtitle: String? = dataWeatherSelectedCity[indexPath.row].country as String
    cell.cellMyCountry.text = cellSubtitle

    cell.cellMyImage.image = UIImage(named: "Blank52")

    var currentCityWeatherURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/\(self.myAPI.kWundergroundApiKey)/conditions/lang:RU/q/zmw:\(self.dataWeatherSelectedCity[indexPath.row].zmv).json"

    var fullObservation:NSDictionary = self.myAPI.jsonParsingWeather(currentCityWeatherURL)
    var currentObservation:NSDictionary = fullObservation.valueForKey("current_observation") as NSDictionary

    var currentWeather = self.myAPI.parsingOneCityCurrentCondition(currentObservation)       
    cell.cellMyImage.image = currentWeather.image
    cell.cellMyTemp.text = currentWeather.temp
    return cell
}
```

Property in TableViewCell:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Table without `self.tableView.registerClass(MyCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)` or `self.tableView.registerClass(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)`:

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing in your post where you did set the _reuse identifier_ in _IB_ for your cell...

Comment: where is the updated picture? I'm not seeing any...

Comment: now you see the pictures in my edited post?

Comment: have you tried `object_getClass(MyCell)` instead of `MyCell.classForCoder()` and `MyCell.self`? that'd look logically more correct to me in _Swift_...

Comment: Just tried - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell'`

Comment: okay, it is time for me working the solution out, because guessing looks not very helpful. :)

Comment: this is full project link on Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tx9l1xnuqfh57je/WeatherTest2%205.zip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As error suggest you are getting your `cell` or `UITestField` `nil` and `Swift` doesn't support method call on nil object that's why you are getting crash. you can prevent crash by checking the object is nil or not as bellow

```
if var label = cell.cellMyCity{
    label.text = cellText
}
```

**EDIT**

I think I got what is the problem here...

You have drag-n-drop `UISearchBar` in your `storyboard`, So by defaults all **data source and delegate** set to your Controller say, `ViewController`(class in which you override UITableView DataSource methods) and in that `ViewController` you register MyCell class as your customize class.
So your tableView displays perfect but when you type something to UISearchBar, same DataSource methods (`ViewController`) called and there as well, you registers MyCell for `searchResultsTableView` (`UISearchDisplayController` tableView thats display search result), but that doesn't know about MyCell and that's why `cell.cellMyCity` is coming as nil in case of search, that means `searchResultsTableView` expect the default `UITableViewCell` and you are not setting anything for default cell like -

```
cell.textLabel.text = countryList[indexPath.row]
```

this whole scenario you can observe by changing you DataSource methods as bellow

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as MyCell!
    if cell == nil {
        //tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UICustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UICustomTableViewCell")
        tableView.registerClass(MyCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)

        cell = MyCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
    }
    if var label = cell.cellMyCity{
        label.text = countryList[indexPath.row]
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel.text = countryList[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

As far as **Solution is concern**, there could be two possible solution..

A). Don't use `searchResultsTableView` (provided by `UISearchDisplayController`) and display your search results in the same `tableView` that you have in your `ViewController`. For that what you can do is - listen to the `UISearchBar`  delegates when user type some thing in `UISearchBar` get your result datasource (May be in different array) by Predicates and Display results in the same `UITableView`.

B). Customize UISearchDisplayController and use your custom cell (i.e MyCell) in `searchResultsTableView`

Comment: Are you getting cell object nil every time??

Comment: If I use `self.tableView.registerClass(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)` - then every time. If I not use this, then all good - table filled. But crush Search Display Controller

Comment: I still don't understand the problem! BUT THIS SOLVED IT

Answer (score 21):

what I did for making that working is something like this:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UICustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UICustomTableViewCell")

        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

*NOTE: If I use the* `–registerClass(_: forCellReuseIdentifier:)` *method, the xib file won't be loaded, therefore the actual custom interface will not appear unless you add the content programatically to the cell. if you'd like to load the interface from a nib file, you need to register the cell with its nib.*

---

conforming the essential protocols:

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell: UICustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(UICustomTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier) as UICustomTableViewCell
        println(cell)
        return cell;
    }
    
}

//

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        return 44.0
    }
    
}
```

---

and the custom cell class was a very generic one with a meaningful name as `UICustomTableViewCell`:

```
class UICustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    class var reuseIdentifier: String {
        get {
            return "UICustomTableViewCell"
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

---

with a quite random interface:

[image: random custom interface]

and these settings of *custom class* and *reuse identifier*:

[image: custom class]
[image: reuse identifier]

---

and the final result on my screen is as I expected with 3 rows:

[image: the final result in practice]

*NOTE: for further customisation of the custom cells you may need extend the code above.*

## UPDATE

with `UISearchBar`, the final result would be like this:

[image: with Search Bar]

Comment: I mean, I definitely need to make xib for a cell? Without it will not work?

Comment: no, you don't need to make xib for a custom cell, you can create the custom content entirety programmatically, if you'd prefer better that way.

Comment: Could you suggest how can I make it in my project?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question... you can add custom views/layers to your custom cell in e.g. the `–init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` or in general you can use the `–willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview:)` or in even the `–didMoveToSuperview()` method for customising a view.

Comment: Ok. Try to use standard table with Search Display Controller

Comment: Without custom `UITableViewCell not work again` :-( `Search Bar and Search Display Controller` crush. Created new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755279/search-bar-and-search-display-controller-in-uitableviewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: I have not experienced any unpleasant behaviour with `UISearchBar`, after I added such thing to my `tableView`, it still works like a charm.

Comment: I think I have a little misunderstood .... I did not use a custom `UITableViewCell`, only the standard `UITableViewController` and `Search Bar and Search Display Controller`. All the same, the application is stopped when trying to click on search.

Comment: that is a huge misunderstanding, because if you are _not_ using custom table cells, what would you like to register for the tableview? and why? the custom cells should be registered only for having better performance while the system loads them in to the memory.

Comment: Due to the fact that there are problems with the `Search Bar and Search Display Controller`, I decided to stop using Custom `UITableViewCell`. I thought that the problem will disappear with the `Search Bar and Search Display Controller`, it has not disappeared. That's why I created a new question where already there is nothing about Custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 10):

Adding `self` before `tableView` fixes the issues:

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell!
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Works for me.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me (XCode 7.2 & Swift v2)

Comment: wtf... can anyone explain why this works?  `self` seems so arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 2):

make sure to remove register class if you are using storyboard as it will overwrite the storyboard and all the outlink associated with it

please check
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26350795/4453583

it works for me =)

Answer (score 1):

You must remember to register the cell for any tableView that use it -- including searchDisplayController.tableView.