# TableView is Nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have the following class:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
    var list: TLListModel!
    var specificList: CKRecord!




    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myContainer = CKContainer.default()
        list = TLListModel(container: myContainer, viewController: self)
        if(listTableView != nil){
            listTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of items: %i", list.lists.count)
        return list.lists.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = listTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
        let list: CKRecord = self.list.lists[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = list.value(forKey: "ListName") as? String
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont (name: "Slim Joe", size: 20)
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("This object has been selected")
        print(self.list.lists[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])

        specificList = self.list.lists[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TLSpecificListSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "TLSpecificListSegue"{
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TLSpecificListViewController{
                destinationVC.listObject = specificList
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if editingStyle == .delete
        {
            let cloudkit = TLCloudKitHelper()            
            cloudkit.deleteListItem(self.list.lists[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row], callback: { (listName) in
                TLAlertHelper.notifyUser("List Deleted", message: NSString(format: "List for %@ successfully deleted", listName) as String, sender: self)

                 let myContainer = CKContainer.default()
                 self.list = TLListModel(container: myContainer, viewController: self)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.listTableView.reloadData()
                }

            })


        }
    }

}
```

When I call it from another view controller using the following method:

```
@IBAction func createListAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let cloudkit = TLCloudKitHelper()
    let listArray = createListFromTextField(textInputArea.text)

    if(!(listNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)!){
        cloudkit.createList(listNameTextField.text!) { (response) in
            let listId = response
            if (!listArray.isEmpty){
                for item in listArray{
                    cloudkit.saveItemRecord(item, listId: listId, recordName: response)
                }
            }
            let fvc: FirstViewController = FirstViewController()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(fvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
    }else{
        TLAlertHelper.notifyUser("Give the list a name", message: "You need to give you list a name...", sender:self)
    }


}
```

I get an error saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I've tried looking at the answers here: [Simple UITableView in Swift - unexpectedly found nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833391/simple-uitableview-in-swift-unexpectedly-found-nil) but I none of those answers helped. Can someone tell me why this this crashing and how I can fix it?

Comment: You should stop using NSIndexPath, by the way.

Comment: @matt I converted to a Swift 3 project. Thanks for the heads up. I'm guessing there are a few things I haven't gotten to yet.

Comment: Yep, the migrator sucks on this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let fvc: FirstViewController = FirstViewController()
```

This creates a *blank* FirstViewController instance — one completely unconnected with the interface you designed *in the storyboard*. Its view is *empty*. It has no table view in it. Therefore, since there is no table view, there is no outlet connection from any table view, and `listTableView` remains `nil`.

What you want to do is get the FirstViewController instance *from the storyboard*, the one whose interface you have already designed *in the storyboard*. You can do that by talking *to the storyboard* and using the FirstViewController's *identifier*, i.e., call `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`. (You might have to *give* the FirstViewController in the storyboard an identifier for this purpose.)

**EDIT** This is such a common mistake that I've written a blog post about it: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: Thanks @matt I never would have got that. This new swift 3 really has me turned around and I feel like things are more complicated now. You use to be able create a view controller and present it. Apparently that isn't the case now. :/

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift 3. Your code would not have worked in Swift 2 either.

Comment: Hmmm... Well maybe it's a storyboard thing. I'm use to using xibs. I've never had this issue before.

Comment: Right, a storyboard thing is exactly what it is, and my answer was wrong. Fixed now, though! Thanks for sticking with me here.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm done massacring that answer. :( Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I think it's right. I just have to figure out how to do everything you suggested. I'll let you know once I have it though. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Finally got it! Thanks for all your help! I really appreciated it. It just goes to show why I hate working with storyboards ;)

Comment: They are not so bad as long as you understand what they are. What didn't click for you is that each scene in a storyboard is a _view controller instance_. It was _that particular instance_ that you needed to talk to. Trust me, your knowledge of xib files and how to do things without segues will _help_ you understand storyboards. You will know what's _really_ going on.

Comment: You're absolutely right about what I didn't understand. I never realized that each was it's own instance. Thanks again for all the help. I appreciate it.