# App crashed on cell initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is the custom class for my cell:

```
class showSugTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "showSug")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


    let categoryLbl = UILabel()
    categoryLbl.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 20)
    categoryLbl.text = "Text"
    contentView.addSubview(categoryLbl)



}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


}

}
```

And here's the code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("showSug") as! showSugTableViewCell


        return cell
```

The problem is that my app crashes on the cell initialisation, and the log says:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

I changed my code to this:

```
   let cellTemp = self.sugTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("showSug")
        var cell = cellTemp as? showSugTableViewCell!

        if cell == nil {
            self.sugTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "showSugTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "showSug")
            self.sugTableView.registerClass(showSugTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "showSug")

            cell = showSugTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "showSug")
        }


        return cell!
```

However, the app now crashed on the return statement.

Comment: by first telling us in what line the error occurred!

Comment: I said it crashed on the cell initialisation, which is  `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("showSug") as! showSugTableViewCell`

Comment: well, to be exact: that is not the initialisation. Have you set up your custom cell in the IB to have the associated `showSug` identifier? Have you set the class of that cell to be `showSugTableViewCell`. Note: classes should start with upper case letters: `ShowSugTableViewCell`

Comment: Split the assignment in two operations: `let cellTemp = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("showSug")` and `let cell = cellTemp as! showSugTableViewCel` and then debug to see what the type of `cellTemp` actually is.

Comment: Actually I did everything programatically, so I'm surely missing something to make it work...

Comment: Yes, then you are missing something. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24752512/2442804) to see how to register your cell for a given identifier

Comment: categoryLbl.text! = "Text" .. try this

Comment: I edited my post @luk2302

Comment: now you mixed up my two suggestions. remove my first suggestion splitting the assignment, implement only the linked solution and remove the nib-statement if you dont have a custom nib-file for the cell.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UITableViewCell register class in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751513/custom-uitableviewcell-register-class-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Try following case to confirm the issue - I strongly believe following 2 issues might   be your problem

```
if let retCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("showSug") {
    if let cell = retCell as? showSugTableViewCell {
        //use the cell object
    }else {
        //1. cell may not be of type showSugTableViewCell so filing t convert
//If it is the case check in identifier you set in nib
    }
}else {
    //2. tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier may not be returning for "showSug"
//Check class type it return table cell
}
```

Comment: I have update my answer - check in your nib and make sure you have configured as expected.

Comment: Would you please tell which error(point 1 or 2) you are receiving ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing how did you solved your issue ?

Comment: I found the solution here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751513/custom-uitableviewcell-register-class-in-swift/24752512#24752512)